# React Router - Take over at root URL

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

So I've got React Router set up and I'm trying to run it from WordPress.

The app routes correctly as long as you start from the root "/". However if you manually navigate to any subpage via the address bar, React Router seems to only take over from there.

For example.

Hitting / will render the homepage. If you click the link 'style-guide' it will correctly route you to /style-guide and render the page.

However, if you manually navigate to /style-guide in your address bar, react will render the homepage there, and if you now click the style-guide link it will bring you to /style-guide/style-guide

What I need to do is tell react-router to always start from the root URL.

My Routes Look Like this

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import PageContainer from 'containers/pageContainer'

class RoutesList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={PageContainer} />
            <Route path="style-guide" component={PageContainer} />
            <Route
              render={() => {
                return <Redirect to="/" />
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default RoutesList
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your routes exact paths

`<Route exact path="/" component={PageContainer} />`

`<Route exact path="/style-guide" component={PageContainer} />`